# How can i get Firefox snap to use the Downloads folder in my home

Tags: firefox, snap

In the Chromium snap, it uses the Downloads folder in my home to save downloaded files, while Firefox uses its own folder inside the snap structure (/home//snap/firefox/common/Downloads).
I tried to make a symlink to a folder in my home, so that i have the folder somewhere more accessible, but when I try to access the folder from another snap (say mailspring) it's not able to access the files.
Is there a smart way to get this to work as you would expect (like Chromium), or is it only something that mozilla has to do when they package it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings in the Firefox app settings?

Comment: wow. such a simple solution, it's amazing i didn't think of it. thank you, that worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for the answer George!  Also reported as bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1535785